# How can I work with sass files (.sass) using Gulp?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass, gulp

I have an  important question to make:

Well i have a bunch of sass files (not scss) and  I'm working with gulp but the problem here is Gulp only acepts scss files

Soo i  wanna know if there's any possibility that my gulp file accepts sass instead of css or both of them.

this  is my gulpfile:

```
function Default () {

browserSync.init({ 
    server: "./src"
});

gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', Sass);
gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change',browserSync.reload);

}

function Sass(){

return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/sass/*.scss'])
.pipe(sass()) //le decimos que vamos a convertir nuestro archivo sass 
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/css")) //le dcemos que lo guarde aquí
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

 exports.default = Default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp accepts type of file with the help of src array passed as parameter in `gulp.src` and also in watch function for the files for which to watch out.

So change in above code to something like this to accept sass as file type(and not scss) and then tell the watcher function to run when sass is changed.

Here `sassdirectoryglob` is the glob that will contain all the `.sass` type files at your location which will be watched.

```
gulp.watch(sassdirectoryglob, Sass);
```

and also for main Sass function where `arrayofsassfiles` should be the main files which only needs to be compiled (not the partials files starting with underscore).

```
function Sass(){

return gulp.src(arrayofsassfiles)
.pipe(sass()) //le decimos que vamos a convertir nuestro archivo sass 
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/css")) //le dcemos que lo guarde aquí
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Comment: Thaanks,  do i have to initialize it first?

Comment: You can just run `npm i gulp-sass` 

const nodeSass = require("gulp-sass");

Comment: Hello,  again. Its me! i've a doubt  with sassdirectoryglob
is it a kind of variable or something like this or is another plugin that i have to install?

Comment: @AlonsoSánchez Globbing is the act of locating files on a filesystem using one or more globs. You can read more https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs/